# Advice on applying Machine learning for high dimentional datasets

Tags: machine-learning, large-data

I am working with a data-set of around ~100000 observations(rows) and ~256 features(columns). Is there any recommendation for applying Machine Learning techniques on such a data-set efficiently ? Maybe by parallelization or similar approaches ?

I am currently using Matlab for applying different Machine Learning, but have investigated Python's scikit-learn as well for applying:

**Regression**

- Gaussian processes for regression GPR

**Classification**

- Linear discriminant analysis LDA
- Support vector machine SVM

Obviously dimentionality reduction comes to mind, however for this specific data-set removing some of the features or applying transformations will distort the information.

Comment: That's less than 200 MB of data in MATLAB double precision. That doesn't sound very big to me.

Comment: @MarkL.Stone The PC is crashing every time i run GPR on the full dataset, or it just runs for hours without any results at the end and i would have to stop it manualy

Comment: Lots of options and methods (algorithms) available https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/fitrgp.html .  Some might make a big difference in run time and success prospects. Have you set verbose to 2 so that you can see intermediate output, progress (or not) being made?

Comment: Your PC is crashing because out of the box gaussian process regression is $\mathcal{O}(n^3)$ (it requires the inversion of the gram matrix). If you want to scale gaussian processes to more than a few thousand data points you need to look into approximate inference methods that specifically can handle 100k data points.

Comment: You problem doesn’t qualify as a big data problem. I suggest revising the title of your question.

Answer (score 3):

Try Gradient Boosting Machine (GBM) and you’ll get results within minutes.

[example with scikit-learn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/ensemble/plot_gradient_boosting_regression.html)

Also check an extremely fast GBM implementation with R and Python bindings: [xgboost](https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost)